# How I Get html element with Ajax using dropdown selected option?

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my dropdown which I load with RSS data from wired.com

```
         <select name="Konular" class="col-md-8" id="rssdrop">
            @foreach (var item in Model.RSSDropDown)
            {
                <option value=@item.Value>@item.Text</option>
            }
        </select>

         <div id="content" style="overflow:scroll; height:300px; width:800px; margin-left:auto">içerik</div>
```

I want to get article tag from link, using ajax and load this into #content.
This is my ajax script:

```
 $("#rssdrop").change(function () {
    var RSSurl = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: RSSurl,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').html($(data).find('article').html());
        }
    });
});
```

when i copy link and past its work like:

```
   url: "https://www.wired.com/story/star-wars-the-last-jedi-review/",
```

but i cant take it from selected option how can I do that

Comment: console.log(RSSurl) .. then let me know ? what are you getting

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code from this :

```
var RSSurl = $(this).find(':selected').val();
```

to this:

```
var RSSurl = $(this).val();
```

.val works well on select element itself, no need to find selected option in that.

Comment: I try it but it said :
Failed to load https://www.wired.com/story/math-says-youre-driving-wrong-and-its-slowing-us-all-down: Redirect from 'https://www.wired.com/story/math-says-youre-driving-wrong-and-its-slowing-us-all-down' to 'https://www.wired.com/story/math-says-youre-driving-wrong-and-its-slowing-us-all-down/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51565' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: oh so its not the problem from select option being not selected. its the cross-origin platform problem. you can't access that url from localhost, as its restricted from accessing other origins for security reasons.

Comment: in simple words, url you are accessing it should have a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to true, only this way it will work.